2D 'Worms' battle like game with anime cartoon tanks circa 2005?
There was a game I played as a child on the internet back in maybe 2005, where it was a 2D worms wmd style battle game, but the characters were different types of tanks with eyes in cartoon art style, almost maple story/anime like but not like anime anime. maybe even Korean style looking cartoon. It also had a tank character that shot only boomerang type missiles and so you had to adjust for the curve and I think Wind speed as well.
I had so many fond memories and remember even chatting with someone who was from Malaysia at the time. it was so cool but I forgot the name of it and its been so long and would love to at least see a video of it again. I doubt it still exists but it was so fun at the time.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Alternately, an incorrect answer is a good opportunity to [edit] further details into your question, e.g. "I know it isn't Tank You Ma'am because none of the artillery was chicken-based".

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

Might it be Gunbound?


Gunbound has turn-based artillery gameplay, bearing properties of two-dimensional games and ballistics-simulation games. In Gunbound, players are assigned to two opposing teams which take turns firing at each other with vehicles called "Mobiles" in Gunbound parlance. Each Mobile has three unique weapons, labeled "1", "2", and "SS" (Special Shot).
Factors like terrain condition, wind currents and elemental phenomena force players to continuously change their aim and trajectory power setting while rethinking their strategy at the same time. Gunbound also implements a "delay" turn system which is influenced by the Mobile, the weapon and/or item a player uses—using items or taking time with actions results in a longer wait before the player's next turn.
Before the start of every game, the room master has the option to disable certain items from being used during that game. All or none of the items could be disabled. Items either take up one or two slots, and each player is allowed to acquire any combination of items as long as they fit in six slots. Generally, strong items take up two slots, while weak items take up one slot. There are currently four different types of items available. They are attack items, defensive items, weather item, and other items.

Boomer's Special Shot can turn into a boomerang.

SS: This shot requires 1.8 seconds of airtime (I think) before it 'opens up'. If you have used armor or turtle's SS you know what I'm talking about. If you don't keep the shot airborne long enough then it simply hits the enemy for a crappy bit of damage (maybe 250ish). If it stays airborne long enough it stops for a split second, flashes, and transforms into a golden boomerang that can inflict 400-600 damage depending on how perfectly centered and 'clean' the hit is. It causes a little bit more splash damage than your other shots, which means a very near miss might be good for 200-300.

Tank Selection

Gameplay



Found with a Google search for 2005 web tank ballistics game

OP here,   bro.. this was IT.  I'm laughing to myself because it looks like you were easily able to find it with a simple google search while I googled so many different variation to no avail.
I deeply appreciate your effort and response.  The nostalgia means alot finding this.

@Dumbledore: No worries. To be frank, the search terms I post are usually the 4th or 5th attempt before something came up. :-D I don't remember how many iterations this took, but I'll typically start with a fairly straightforward query based on keywords in the question, and then start adjusting them based on results.

Good insight, A boss nevertheless.  Thank you again @FuzzyBoots! may you thrive and prosper!
